# Css divs alignment layout

Tags: css, css-float, responsive-design, html

I have a problem with a css divs alignment. 
I think that the alignment is incorrect. Right now is on the left and would be better centered.

http://bit.ly/VOqkhw

I tried with the div ".post" and the floating but not work. Is it possible to solve this ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such layouts usually require heavy use of Javascript.
One of the ways to acheive what you're trying to is to create N columns and dynamically fill them using JS + hide/show the columns using @media queries. In this case HTML would go something like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="post">
        ...
        </div>
        <div class="post">
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="post">
        ...
        </div>
        <div class="post">
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On `$(window).resize()` (jQuery) you'd add or remove `column`s and re-arrange `post`s based on their width and height. And you'd use the media queries to set the width of the displayed columns, pretty much like so:

```
@media all and (max-width:1000px) {
    .column{width:50%;} /*that would make two equal columns
    when the screen width <=1000 */
}

@media all and (max-width:1500px) {
    .column{width:33.3333%;} /*that would make three equal columns
    when the screen width <=1500 */
}

.post {width:100%;}
.column {float:left;}
```

If you'd provide more details - you'd get a more detailed answer and less downvotes.

Comment: ok! I will try to check the mediaqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to put the div postwrapper in the foliogrid div and then put a text-align center on the foliogrid.